# Error during installation of pip on win10

Tags: windows, command-line, pip

i've run into some problems while trying to install pip on win10, I can't understand from where it's coming from, here's what the error looks like:

I run the command *python get-pip.py --prefix=/usr/local/*

And the cmd responded with an error:

> Collecting pip
>     Using cached   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4a/08/6ca123073af4ebc4c5488a5bc8a010ac57aa39ce4d3c8a931ad504de4185/pip-19.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Installing collected packages: pip
>     Found existing installation: pip 19.3
>       Uninstalling pip-19.3:
>         Successfully uninstalled pip-19.3
>     Rolling back uninstall of pip
>     Moving to c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip-19.3.dist-info\
>      from c:\python27\lib\site-packages\~ip-19.3.dist-info
>     Moving to c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\
>      from c:\python27\lib\site-packages\~ip
>     Moving to c:\python27\scripts\pip.exe
>      from c:\users\rpupi\appdata\local\temp\pip-uninstall-0vhfjn\pip.exe
>     Moving to c:\python27\scripts\pip2.7.exe
>      from c:\users\rpupi\appdata\local\temp\pip-uninstall-0vhfjn\pip2.7.exe
>     Moving to c:\python27\scripts\pip2.exe
>      from c:\users\rpupi\appdata\local\temp\pip-uninstall-0vhfjn\pip2.exe
>   ERROR: Exception:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "c:\users\rpupi\appdata\local\temp\tmp72f5up\pip.zip\pip_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 188, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)
>     File "c:\users\rpupi\appdata\local\temp\tmp72f5up\pip.zip\pip_internal\commands\install.py", line 407, in run
>       use_user_site=options.use_user_site,
>     File "c:\users\rpupi\appdata\local\temp\tmp72f5up\pip.zip\pip_internal\req__init__.py", line 58, in install_given_reqs
>       **kwargs
>     File "c:\users\rpupi\appdata\local\temp\tmp72f5up\pip.zip\pip_internal\req\req_install.py", line 928, in install
>       use_user_site=use_user_site, pycompile=pycompile,
>     File "c:\users\rpupi\appdata\local\temp\tmp72f5up\pip.zip\pip_internal\req\req_install.py", line 461, in move_wheel_files
>       warn_script_location=warn_script_location,
>     File "c:\users\rpupi\appdata\local\temp\tmp72f5up\pip.zip\pip_internal\wheel.py", line 326, in move_wheel_files
>       prefix=prefix,
>     File "c:\users\rpupi\appdata\local\temp\tmp72f5up\pip.zip\pip_internal\locations.py", line 111, in distutils_scheme
>       i.finalize_options()
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 38, in finalize_options
>       orig.install.finalize_options(self)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 353, in finalize_options
>       'userbase', 'usersite')
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 504, in convert_paths
>       setattr(self, attr, convert_path(getattr(self, attr)))
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\util.py", line 124, in convert_path
>       raise ValueError, "path '%s' cannot be absolute" % pathname
>   ValueError: path '/usr/local//Lib/site-packages' cannot be absolute

Thanks if you know how to fix this. ANd feel free to ask anything you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `raise ValueError, "path '%s' cannot be absolute" % pathname` is relatively generic as far as I am aware. You may wish to try `python get-pip.py --prefix=/usr/local` but that is just a guess.

However, you question raises more in my mind:

- `pip` is installed with Python in most cases, so why are you even running `python get-pip.py`?
- How did you install Python? `C:\Python27` is usually associated with vanilla Python from [Python.org](https://www.python.org/) in my experience. Did you get from Python there, from the Windows store or somewhere else (e.g. via [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/))?
- Why are you adding `--prefix=/usr/local`? `/usr/local` is a Linux directory and only makes (possible) sense if you are running under the [Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10). Is that what you are using?

Comment: Just hit the same bug in a MinGW cross-compile prefix on Linux. Removing `--prefix` did the trick.